# Сбрасывает сетевой alias адрес при потере сети

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, alias, ifconfig

Имеется *Ubuntu 14.04*, добавляю сетевой alias следующей командой:

> `sudo ifconfig eth0:0 <новый_ip> up`

При потере соединения (выдергивание кабеля, уход в "сон") псевдоним сбрасывается. Почему? Как этого избежать?

Comment: Добавить в конфиг? И настоятельно рекомендую использовать утилиту `ip` из набора `iproute2` .

Comment: @nobody в какой конфиг? Мне не нужен перманентный alias, я хочу чтобы он держался до следующей перезагрузки.

Comment: Ну Вам в любом случае нужно будет что-то, что будет реагировать на события ifup/ifdown - скрипт, программа, etc. , чтоб добавлять адрес обратно. Сначала попробуйте ещё разок добавить но уже с помощью утилиты `ip` в рантайм: `ip addr add <новый_ip> dev eth0` - если всё равно будет "пропадать" , попробуйте посмотреть что у Вас в `/etc/network/interfaces` и добавить туда событие при поднятии eth0.

Comment: @nobody добавление alias по Вашему способу не позволяет достучаться до устройств в новой подсети. Т.е. я вижу только <новый_ip>, поэтому такой вариант не подходит.

Comment: @nobody, маску забыли: ip-адрес/маска

Comment: Хм, `ip addr add <новый_ip>/<маска_новой_подсети_с_устройствами> dev eth0` ?

Comment: @nobody с маской пингует. Но выдергивание кабеля всё равно сбрасывает адрес. Если я пропишу в `/etc/network/interfaces` это будет уже на постоянной основе. Этого хотелось бы избежать.

Comment: @alexolut дык, а если его потом просто оттуда удалить? :)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ага спасибо :)

Comment: @nobody просто удалить, просто добавить, просто забыть :) Хочу найти решение, которое самоустраняется при перезагрузке.

Comment: Ну-у-у-у, можно написать в `rc.local` "скрипт" который с помощью `sed` будет заменять строку `up ip addr add <новый_ip>/<маска_новой_подсети_с_устройствами> dev eth0` на пробел ^_^